# FileStream Vs System.IO.File.WriteAllText when writing to files

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have seen many examples/ tutorials about VB.NET or C#.NET where the author is using a `FileStream` to write/read from a file. My question is there any benefit to this method rather than using `System.IO.File.Read/Write` ? Why are the majority of examples using `FileStream` to when the same can be achieved using just a single line of code?

Comment: `WriteAllText` is great when you have a single string that you want to write to a file. But if you have a whole lot of strings to write, it's easier to write to a `StreamWriter` rather than build up a single string and then write that using `WriteAllText`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`FileStream` gives you a little more control over writing files, which can be beneficial in certain cases. It also allows you to **keep the file handle open** and **continuously write data without relinquishing control**. Some use cases for a stream:

- Multiple inputs
- Real time data from a memory/network stream.

`System.IO.File` contains wrappers around file operations for basic actions such as saving a file, reading a file to lines, etc. It's simply an abstraction over `FileStream`.

From the .NET source code here is what [`WriteAllText`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,f73b33d2cc64e5db) does internally:

```
private static void InternalWriteAllText(string path,
    string contents, Encoding encoding)
{
    Contract.Requires(path != null);
    Contract.Requires(encoding != null);
    Contract.Requires(path.Length > 0);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding))
        sw.Write(contents);
}
```

Comment: A common usecase to prefer FileStream over File.* is to control locking of a file.